# error while storing in Hbase using Pig

Tags: hadoop, hbase, apache-pig, store, hortonworks-data-platform

hadoop dfs input data cat:

```
[ituser1@genome-dev3 ~]$ hadoop fs -cat FOR_COPY/COMPETITOR_BROKERING/part-r-00000 | head -1
```

returns:

```
836646827,1000.0,2016-02-20,34,CAPITAL BOOK,POS/CAPITAL BOOK/NEW DELHI/200216/14:18,BOOKS AND STATIONERY,5497519004453567/41043516,MARRIED,M,SALARIED,D,5942,1
```

My Pig code:

```
DATA = LOAD 'FOR_COPY/COMPETITOR_BROKERING' USING PigStorage(',') AS (CUST_ID:chararray,TXN_AMT:chararray,TXN_DATE:chararray,AGE_CASA:chararray,MERCH_NAME:chararray,TXN_PARTICULARS:chararray,MCC_CATEGORY:chararray,TXN_REMARKS:chararray,MARITAL_STATUS_CASA:chararray,GENDER_CASA:chararray,OCCUPATION_CAT_V2_NEW:chararray,DR_CR:chararray,MCC_CODE:chararray,OCCURANCE:int);

DATA_FIL = FOREACH DATA GENERATE                
                (chararray)CUST_ID AS CUST_ID,
                (chararray)TXN_AMT AS TXN_AMT,
                (chararray)TXN_DATE AS TXN_DATE,
                (chararray)AGE_CASA AS AGE_CASA,
                (chararray)MERCH_NAME AS MERCH_NAME,
                (chararray)TXN_PARTICULARS AS TXN_PARTICULARS,
                (chararray)MCC_CATEGORY AS MCC_CATEGORY,
                (chararray)TXN_REMARKS AS TXN_REMARKS,
                (chararray)MARITAL_STATUS_CASA AS MARITAL_STATUS_CASA,
                (chararray)GENDER_CASA AS GENDER_CASA,
                (chararray)OCCUPATION_CAT_V2_NEW AS OCCUPATION_CAT_V2_NEW,
                (chararray)DR_CR AS DR_CR,
                (chararray)MCC_CODE AS MCC_CODE;

STORE DATA_FIL INTO 'hbase://TXN_EVENTS' USING org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.hbase.HBaseStorage ('DETAILS:CUST_ID DETAILS:TXN_AMT DETAILS:TXN_DATE DETAILS:AGE_CASA DETAILS:MERCH_NAME DETAILS:TXN_PARTICULARS DETAILS:MCC_CATEGORY DETAILS:TXN_REMARKS DETAILS:MARITAL_STATUS_CASA DETAILS:GENDER_CASA DETAILS:OCCUPATION_CAT_V2_NEW DETAILS:DR_CR DETAILS:MCC_CODE');
```

but Giving error:

```
ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser - ERROR 2244: Job job_1457792710587_0100 failed, hadoop does not return any error message
```

But my Load is working perfectly:

```
HDATA = LOAD 'hbase://TXN_EVENTS'
       USING org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.hbase.HBaseStorage(
       'DETAILS:CUST_ID DETAILS:TXN_AMT DETAILS:TXN_DATE DETAILS:AGE_CASA DETAILS:MERCH_NAME DETAILS:TXN_PARTICULARS DETAILS:MCC_CATEGORY DETAILS:TXN_REMARKS DETAILS:MARITAL_STATUS_CASA DETAILS:GENDER_CASA DETAILS:OCCUPATION_CAT_V2_NEW DETAILS:DR_CR DETAILS:MCC_CODE','-loadKey true' )
       AS (ROWKEY:chararray,CUST_ID:chararray,TXN_AMT:chararray,TXN_DATE:chararray,AGE_CASA:chararray,MERCH_NAME:chararray,TXN_PARTICULARS:chararray,MCC_CATEGORY:chararray,TXN_REMARKS:chararray,MARITAL_STATUS_CASA:chararray,GENDER_CASA:chararray,OCCUPATION_CAT_V2_NEW:chararray,DR_CR:chararray,MCC_CODE:chararray);
```

DUMP HDATA; (this gives perfect result):

```
2016-03-01,1,20.0,2016-03-22,27,test_merch,test/particulars,test_category,test/remarks,married,M,service,D,1234
```

A help is appreciated

I am using Horton stack in distributed mode:

HDP2.3
Apache Pig version 0.15.0
HBase 1.1.1

Also all jars are in place as I have installed them through Ambari.

Comment: can you check the logs and post them too ?

Comment: org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 2244: Job job_1457792710587_0105 failed, hadoop does not return any error message
        at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.executeBatch(GruntParser.java:179)
        at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:234)
        at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:205)
        at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt.exec(Grunt.java:81)

Comment: at org.apache.pig.Main.run(Main.java:631)
        at org.apache.pig.Main.main(Main.java:177)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved the data upload :

as i was missing to Rank the relation , hence hbase rowkey becomes the rank.\

DATA_FIL_1 = RANK DATA_FIL_2;

NOTE: this will generate arbitrary rowkey.

But if you want to **define your row key** then use like:

you have to give another relation , only STORE function won't work.
this will take first tuple as rowkey(which you have defined)

**storage_data** = STORE DATA_FIL INTO 'hbase://genome:event_sink' USING org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.hbase.HBaseStorage('event_data:CUST_ID event_data:EVENT transaction_data:TXN_AMT transaction_data:TXN_DATE transaction_data:AGE_CASA transaction_data:MERCH_NAME transaction_data:TXN_PARTICULARS transaction_data:MCC_CATEGORY transaction_data:TXN_REMARKS transaction_data:MARITAL_STATUS_CASA transaction_data:GENDER_CASA transaction_data:OCCUPATION_CAT_V2_NEW transaction_data:DR_CR transaction_data:MCC_CODE');